# How to configuration the WkHtmlToPdf in PHP

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, pdf-conversion, phpwkhtmltopdf

How to configure the WkHtmlToPdf in PHP?

I download the file from the below link of the GitHub through composer but I cannot configure in php

Please help me to configure the WkHtmlToPdf in php

This is the library I am using
https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

Comment: Please add what you have attempted.

Comment: I am having one html file with image's and style.I can't covert file as pdf with style's

Comment: edit your post to include the code you have tried so far with

Answer (score 2):

Add variable declaration line in your `config.php`:

```
$path_htmltopdf = 'C:\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe';
```